# Reachability: 4G internet works on iPhone but SCNetworkReachability flag isn't right

Tags: ios, iphone, reachability

Hi downloaded the sample project "reachability" from apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html
I ran the project on a iPhone and got this in the logs
when beeing in wwan mode (no wifi)

`2018-03-22 17:45:25.057075+0100 Reachability[27045:10299120] Reachability Flag Status: WR t------ networkStatusForFlags`

meening that it has wwan connectivity enabled and is reachable.

I copied the two files "reachability.h" and "reachability.m" in my project, copied the code that  add the observer and test the connectivity,

run it into the very same iPhone, I got this:

`2018-03-22 17:46:04.746101+0100 FastSignerIPadv2[27053:10300902] Reachability Flag Status: W- ------- networkStatusForFlags`

It tells me that there is no internet connection.

I checked the project configurations, but I can't find why reachability tells me that there is no way to make an internet connection, as this is the same code as the sample project, and I can go on the internet using the Iphone in this mode.
When in WIFI, everything works, it logs as expected:

`2018-03-22 18:11:46.287423+0100 Reachability[27064:10309469] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,  the option "mobile data" in the app setting appears only after the first internet connection the app make (it seems). It was "false" in my application settings. Everything is fine when I enable it.